# NotificationCompat.Builder setLights(); not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the LED on my notification and it's not working, i have this code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
nBuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN, 1000, 500);
```

The entire notification is working, like ContentTitle, ContentText and the notification is shown, but only the LED is not working.

Is there anything wrong with my code ? Should i use the `Notification` instead `NotificationCompact.Builder` ?

Comment: Not all hardware supports notifications controlling an LED.

Comment: But all other notifications on my phone can use the LED, like Facebook, that uses a blue led, or WhatsApp, where i can choose the color. Only my app can't blink the LED.

Comment: it works with Notification and with Notification.Builder and with NotificationCompat.Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code seems **OK**, for the APIs **before 26**.
You might try adding    Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
nBuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN, 1000, 500);

Notification notif = nBuilder.build();
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(0, notif);
```

Also make sure that you **do not swipe down** to preview the notification, otherwise the LED will be off when the display goes black.

Answer (score 13):

The LED light for notifications is turned on by the OS in the device *only if* the notification is triggered while the device screen is off.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can not work, because you have to pass three variables:

1. the color
2. if turning on the led is on
3. if turning off the led is on

if you enable 2 and 3 your led will be blinking, if you disable 2 and 3 the led will be turned off

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context );
mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 1, 1); // will blink
```

Comment: This will not blink. Only if you have alien eyes... 1ms

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Jawad, this is not 1 ms, this is a boolean flag 1 = true.

Comment: setLights(int argb, int onMs, int offMs)  from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html. Did I miss something?

Comment: yes, this is not NotificationBuilder, this is NotificationCompat in an old version

Comment: setLights(int argb, int onMs, int offMs) from [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)... Did I miss something?

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder  setLights(int argb, int onMs, int offMs)

Set the argb value that you would like the LED on the device to blink, as well as the rate.....This from developer website. Clearly states that onMs and offMs control the RATE of blink?.........Thank you for the insight that has been offered but honestly how are we supposed to know how to use Android when Android can't even give us clear and reliable info...extremely frustrating once again....YAY for Android!

Comment: Still does not work on ZTE Axon 7 Running Android 6.01. Screen is turned off.          setLights(Color.BLUE, 1, 1);         Does anyone know why certain hardware doesn't allow the controlling of an LED light? Is this some type of security measure I don't understand?

Comment: @JamisonMan111 hello Jamison, they change the interface on nearly all occasions, ... the documentation is bad, there are several hidden API Keys, that provide multiple solutions to known issues, but those are kept secret, ... I would not consider Android to be an real open source project, it is in between and very badly documented, ... if you want to buy a book, where you gain at least basic concepts, i can receommend "Professional Android" (978-1118949528), it is a patch-work assembled book from different sources, but provides the flattest introduction into Android Development... kr, Erdinc