# NotificationCompat.Builder setLights(); not working

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I ready carefully the link I listed, but it's not working, and I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I have to add the same question again. The link like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276363/notificationcompat-builder-setlights-not-working/26636063#26636063)

---

**My code is like this：**

```
final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//点击通知执行下面的事件
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,TestActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

final Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        .setContentTitle("你有一封新的邮件")
        .setContentText("鉴于你最近优秀表现，给你一个小红星")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wechat_fav)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0,500})
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
        .setLights(0xffffffff, 300, 300 )
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .build();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        manager.notify(1,noti);
    }
},4000);
```

---

As you see, I set a Handler to delayed notification to work, and I even turn off the screen, but still didn't work, but the title and content show, and the phone vibrates.

In addition, I also set the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

Comment: well the above stated permission is not required as per your question.

Comment: Have the same issue on android 7 on a Galaxy note 5